# How to capture content typed in a rich text editor div - Quill rich editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, quil

I am trying to fetch content that has been typed in the editor div of quill editor http://quilljs.com/examples/ using jquery codes  but it does not seem to work. It works for other text inputs but not for the editor div. I have a running illustration below .

```js
$(function(){
$(document).on("click", "#SubmitButton", function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

{    
  var question = $("#question").val();  
        var title = $("#title").val();
  
        alert (question);
    alert (title);
   
  e.preventDefault(); 
}
}); 
});

advancedEditor = new Quill('#question', {
  modules: {
    'toolbar': 
 {  
  container: '#toolbar'
    },
    'link-tooltip': true,
    'image-tooltip': true,
    'multi-cursor': true
  },
  styles: false,
  theme: 'snow'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.quilljs.com/0.20.1/quill.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdn.quilljs.com/0.20.1/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<form id="postform" name="postform" action="">  

Title
<input  type="text" name="title" id="title">
<br>
     
     
<div class="advanced-wrapper" id="qs" style="width:95%; padding:0px; margin:0px;">
        <div class="toolbar-container" id="toolbar"><span class="ql-format-group">
            <select title="Font" class="ql-font">
              <option value="sans-serif" selected>Sans Serif</option>
              <option value="Georgia, serif">Serif</option>
              <option value="Monaco, 'Courier New', monospace">Monospace</option>
            </select>
            <select title="Size" class="ql-size">
              <option value="10px">Small</option>
              <option value="13px" selected>Normal</option>
              <option value="18px">Large</option>
              <option value="32px">Huge</option>
            </select></span><span class="ql-format-group"><span title="Bold" class="ql-format-button ql-bold"></span><span class="ql-format-separator"></span><span title="Italic" class="ql-format-button ql-italic"></span><span class="ql-format-separator"></span><span title="Underline" class="ql-format-button ql-underline"></span></span><span class="ql-format-group">
            <select title="Text Color" class="ql-color">
    
              <option value="rgb(187, 187, 187)"></option>
              <option value="rgb(161, 0, 0)"></option>
              
            </select><span class="ql-format-separator"></span>
            <select title="Background Color" class="ql-background">
              <option value="rgb(0, 0, 0)"></option>
              <option value="rgb(230, 0, 0)"></option>
            </select><span class="ql-format-separator"></span>
            <select title="Text Alignment" class="ql-align">
              <option value="left" selected></option>
              <option value="center"></option>
              <option value="right"></option>
              <option value="justify"></option>
            </select></span><span class="ql-format-group"><span title="Link" class="ql-format-button ql-link"></span><span class="ql-format-separator"></span><span title="Image" class="ql-format-button ql-image"></span><span class="ql-format-separator"></span><span title="List" class="ql-format-button ql-list"></span></span></div>
          <div id="question" class="editor-container"></div>
      </div>

<input  type="submit" class="btn btn-info"    id="SubmitButton" value="Post Your Question" />
      </form>
```

I want when i click the submit button, It captures also the content typed in the text editor div and alerts the values types.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quill has it's own API for content retrieval. Replacing your click method with following code should allow you to get the plain text value from your Quill instance.

```
$(document).on("click", "#SubmitButton", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();   
  var question = advancedEditor.getText();
  var title = $("#title").val();    
  console.log(title, question);
});
```

[Here's a link to Quill's documentation for retrieval methods](http://quilljs.com/docs/api/#quillprototypegettext)

Comment: @hootstheowl what if I need HTML formatted text, that I can store & show on another page in a plain div?

Answer (score 1):

First add all the libraries for quilljs and use getText method to get the contents.

```
    <!-- Theme included stylesheets -->
    <link href="//cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.0/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.0/quill.bubble.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Core build with no theme, formatting, non-essential modules -->
    <link href="//cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.0/quill.core.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.0/quill.core.js"></script>
    <!-- Include stylesheet -->
    <link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.0/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.0/quill.js"></script>
    <script>
    document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function(){
        var text =quill.getText( 0, 50); 
    alert(text);
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I see the question is jQuery-oriented, but the JavaScript concept is fairly parallel. Here is how I did it, for you Express folks. It seems to have worked very well in conjunction with express-sanitizer.

**app.js**

```
 import expressSanitizer from 'express-sanitizer'

 app.use(expressSanitizer())

 app.post('/route', async (req, res) => {
     const title = req.body.article.title
     const content = req.sanitize(req.body.article.content)
     // Do stuff with content
 })
```

**new.ejs**

```
 <head>
     <link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.2/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">
 </head>

 ...

 <form action="/route" method="POST">
     <input type="text" name="article[title]" placeholder="Enter Title">
     <div id="editor"></div>
     <input type="submit" onclick="return quillContents()" />
 </form>

 ...

 <script src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.2/quill.js"></script>
 <script>
     const quill = new Quill('#editor', {
         theme: 'snow'
     })

     const quillContents = () => {
         const form = document.forms[0]
         const editor = document.createElement('input')

         editor.type = 'hidden'
         editor.name = 'article[content]'
         editor.value = document.querySelector('.ql-editor').innerHTML
         form.appendChild(editor)

         return form.submit()
     }
</script>
```

`express-sanitizer` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-sanitizer)

`document.forms` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/forms)

My view only has one form, so I used `document.forms[0]`, but if you have multiple or may extend your view in the future to have multiple forms, check out the MDN reference.

What we are doing here is creating a hidden form input that we assign the contents of the Quill Div, and then we bootleg the form submit and pass it through our function to finish it off.

Now, to test it, make a post with `<script>alert()</script>` in it, and you won't have to worry about injection exploits.

That's all there is to it.

> What you want to focus on, in my opinion, is `document.querySelector('.ql-editor').innerHTML` Punch that into your `console.log()` and you will see the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

My solution for version 1.2.2 is:

First import css and js in HEAD

```
<link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.2.2/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.2.2/quill.js"></script>
```

In your HTML body declare a div with id

```
<div id="content_email" name="content_email"></div>
```

In your scripts section declare the editor

```
<script>
  var quill = new Quill('#content_email', {
    theme: 'snow'
  });
</script>
```

And finally to get the content with HTML tags, put this inside an onclick function:

```
var content = document.querySelector('.ql-editor').innerHTML;
console.log("content: ", content);
```