# How to get data from quils to send to server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, quill

I am using quill as a text editor. [Quill Editor](https://quilljs.com/)

I need to get the data from the editor to send to server in a ajax call.

I am using `getContent()` function but it is returning a delta object?

How do I get the data in the parsed form?

Comment: [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44509082/3585500) if you want the raw html. But also read the [linked issue discussion](https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/87).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just in case someone face the same problem. The data in html can be retrive using

```
html = editor.root.innerHTML;
```

A link to working code and other method [here](https://codepen.io/k3no/pen/amwpqk)

Answer (score 0):

I use this to get the content

```
<div id="editor-container"></div>

let quill = new Quill('#editor-container');

let content = quill.editor.scroll.domNode.innerHTML;
```