# How to save Quill.js values to Database Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5, quill

I'm trying to use Quill.js - Your Powerful Rich Text Editor for my project in laravel.

But, since quill uses:

```
<div id="editor"></div> || <div id="editor" name="body"></div>
```

Instead of a regular old:

```
<textarea id="editor" name="body"></textarea>
```

`$post->body = $request->input('body')`; won't work.

What do I use to save the information I get from a div with the id of #editor into a database.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following in JavaScript:

```
var content = document.querySelector("#editor").innerHTML
```

Then append that to your form input before its submitted.

You can also get it directly from the quill instance via:

```
quill.root.innerHTML
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a hidden input :

```
<input type="hidden" name="body"/>
```

Js code :

```
var form = document.getElementById("FormId"); // get form by ID

form.onsubmit = function() { // onsubmit do this first
                             var name = document.querySelector('input[name=body]'); // set name input var
                             name.value = JSON.stringify(quill.getContents()); // populate name input with quill data
                             return true; // submit form
                           }
```

To set contents to quill do this :

```
quill.setContents({!! $post->body !!});
```